# TeamCity Agent Push Failure when Checking Platform

Tags: cloud, teamcity, teamcity-9.0

When attempting to install an agent using the Agent Push feature I get the following error:

```
[12:05:15]: AgentPush v32407 - Install Agent on remote host
[12:05:15]: Looking for Target Host...
[12:05:15]: Validating TeamCity Server Root URL 'http://####' ...
[12:05:19]: Starting agent push to '###'(IP: ###) using preset 'Packer Baker' (Username 'administrator'. Target platform: 'Windows')
[12:05:19]: Checking Platform...
[12:05:24]: 'ssw0rd'' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[12:05:24]: operable program or batch file.
[12:05:24]: Executing command: 'C:\Tomcat\temp\___1655843086080428423\cli-wrapper.exe D:\TMC-Data\system\pluginData\psexec\psexec.exe /accepteula \\### -e -h -u administrator -p ********** cmd.exe /C ver'
[12:05:24]: Remote agent installation failed: Command 'C:\Tomcat\temp\___1655843086080428423\cli-wrapper.exe D:\TMC-Data\system\pluginData\psexec\psexec.exe /accepteula \\### -e -h -u administrator -p ********** cmd.exe /C ver' was executed with error message(s): Execution error. Return code=1
```

Any ideas what might cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by not escaping the ampersand character in the "Credentials to push agent" password.

In the above case I used the password `P&ssw0rd`. When the command

```
C:\Tomcat\temp\___1655843086080428423\cli-wrapper.exe D:\TMC-Data\system\pluginData\psexec\psexec.exe /accepteula \\### -e -h -u administrator -p ********** cmd.exe /C ver
```

is executed `&` is used to run multiple commands on the same line and requires escaping.

After escaping the `&` with `^` and changing the password to `P^&ssw0rd` the agent push ran successfully.